# Given a list of words, how to develop an algorithmic way to semantically group them?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means, similarity, hierarchical-clustering

I am working with the Google Places API, and they contain a [list](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) of 97 different locations. I want to reduce the list of locations into a lesser number
of them, as many of them are groupable. For example, `atm` and `bank` into `financial`; `temple`, `church`, `mosque`, `synagogue` into `worship`; `school`, `university` into `education`; `subway_station`, `train_station`, `transit_station`, `gas_station` into `transportation`.

But also, it should not overgeneralize; for example, `pet_store`, `city_hall`, `courthouse`, `restaurant` into something like `buildings`.

I tried quite a few methods to do this. First I downloaded synonyms of each of the 97 words in the list from multiple dictionaries. Then, I found out the similarity between 2 words based on what fraction of unique synonyms they share in common (Jaccard similarity):

[image]

But after that, how do I group words into clusters? Using traditional clustering methods (k-means, k-medoid, hierarchical clustering, and FCM), I am not getting any good clustering (I identified several misclassifications by scanning the results manually):

[image]
[image]

I even tried the word2vec model trained on Google news data (where each word is expressed as a vector of 300 features), and I do not get good clusters based on that as well:
[image]

Comment: in my opinion your question  is off topic for so

Comment: @InferOn: Just because you don't understand a question doesn't mean it's off-topic.

Comment: @InferOn I know my question is not exactly a programming question, but I need some ideas about how to go about it. And since I do not know of any other platform where I could ask for ideas, I turned to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't think there is a good solution for this. Several taxonomies are possible, for example you could classify the places if you go there for work or for fun.

Comment: @Henry Exactly! Therefore, I do not want to cluster based on context; I want to cluster purely based on the words' meanings in English. Would it not be possible to do so?

Comment: This is only possible if the words are eaxct synonyms (which is not often the case). Otherwise you would have to find some common property, probably out of several alternatives depending on context.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 it is not a programming question, there is a dedicated site for that. btw is not my business

Comment: @InferOn: Believe it or not, but there are a lot of fields in software engineering that do not revolve around JavaScript and C#. May of these fields involve concepts and math.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 in fact there is https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something related to vector space dimensionality reduction. In these techniques, you'll need a corpus of text that uses the locations as words in the text. Dimensionality reduction will then group the terms together. You can do some reading on [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) and Latent semantic indexing. A good reference is "[Introduction to Information Retrieval](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/)" by Manning et al., chapter 18. Note that this book is from 2009, so a lot of advances are not captured. As you noted, there has been a lot of work such as word2vec. Another good reference is "[Speech and Language Processing](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/)" by Jurafsky and Martin, chapter 16.

Comment: I did check up on Latent Dirichlet Allocation. The problem is, I only have the words - I do not have a document, or a collection of sentences, using each word. Therefore, I am not sure how I can use LDA. Any ideas?

Comment: Just google for "NLP newspaper corpus" or "NLP web corpus". There will be plenty of results.

Comment: @Kristada673: Since you are dealing with physical locations, I would also recommend searching for corpora about tourism, travel, and local businesses.

Answer (score 1):

You need **much** more data.

No algorithm ever, without additional data, will relate `ATM` and `bank` to `financial`. Because that requires *knowledge* of these terms.

Jaccard similarity doesn't have access to such knowledge, it can only work on the words. And then "river bank" and "bank branch" are very similar.

So don't expect magic to happen by the algorithm. You need the magic to be in the data...

Comment: I know. That's why I created a list of their synonyms myself, which I wrote above: "First I downloaded synonyms of each of the 97 words in the list from multiple dictionaries. Then, I found out the similarity between 2 words based on what fraction of unique synonyms they share in common (Jaccard similarity)".

Comment: The synonyms won't help that much either. How many synonyms do you get, after you **remove all unique words**? You get next to no similarity information. It's not enough data. You could try to find a Wikipedia article for each, then measure the textual similarity of the entire articles, then it may start working. Or you use all web pages that mention this thing.